# Get select box values of advanced custom field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a repeater field type of a field.The parent field name is  'map_details' and the sub field name is 'name_of_county' which is a select dropdown list.

Now I want to display all the values of that select box in the frontend.My code is

```
$field_key = "field_535befe551ba5"; //field key of parent
$field = get_field_object($field_key); 

if( $field )
{
    echo '<select name="' . $field['key'] . '">';
        foreach( $field['choices'] as $k => $v )
        {
            echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

it's not working as I have given the field key of parent not the sub field which is basically a select box.Also I can't find the field key for the sub field.

How can I display the sub field dropdown box with values and keys in the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

I recently find the way to output the values/keys in the frontend:
In these cases, I always print_r the parent array (between 'pre' tags) in order to understand what's going on, trust me... it helps.
As in a repeater, the select field (sub_field) is one step deeper in the array, so:

```
$field_key = "field_535befe551ba5"; //field key of parent
$field = get_field_object($field_key); 

if( $field ) {

    // As explained, it's better to first take a look to
    // the array's structure. Uncomment the next 3 lines
    // to print it in a pretty way

    // echo '<pre>';
    // print_r ($field);
    // echo '</pre>';

    foreach ($field['sub_fields'] as $the_subfield) {
        $the_subfield_name = $the_subfield['name'];

        // in case that you have more than one subfield in the repeater
        // we need to check that we are in the desired subfield:
        if ($the_subfield_name == 'name_of_the_subfield') {
        //in your case: 'name_of_country'

            // now that we are sure that we are inside the desired
            // subfield, we will output the different choices available
            echo '<select name="' . $the_subfield['name'] . '">';
            foreach( $the_subfield['choices'] as $k => $v ) {
                echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!